# Semantic HTML tag for displaying a path/directory?

Tags: html, path, tags, semantics

Is there any tag that's suited to markup a path or directory?

For example: `<path>user/project/</path>`

I've checked all new HTML5 tags but there doesn't seem to be one that fits this purpose. So which one would come close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't anything in HTML for that. You could try to wrap it in a `<pre>` tag or `<code>` in HTML5. Otherwise you can use a `<span>` tag and style it how you want it to look like.

Answer (score 10):

> The **code** element represents a fragment
>   of computer code. This could be an XML
>   element name, a **filename**, a computer
>   program, or any other string that a
>   computer would recognize.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/textlevel-semantics.html#the-code-element

Answer (score 1):

If it's part of code, you could use a `code.path`.

If it's some sample output you could use `samp.path`.

If you'd like to list the parts, you could use `ol.path` and style the way it's displayed:

```
<ol class="path">
  <li class="dir">user</li>
  <li class="dir">project</li>
<ol>
```

But if it's just a path, you should wrap it with `span.path`.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this:

```
<input type="text" value="user/project/" readonly="readonly" />
```

One advantage is that you can easily select the complete path without selecting other text accidentally. On the other hand it's not quite semantic since it's a form element.