# In HTML, what is the suggested tag to mark up file paths?

Tags: html, tags

What is the suggested replacement of `sometag` in this context:

```
<p>Please find the configuration in <sometag>/etc/important.conf</sometag>.</p>
```

Is there an established standard for this situation?

Comment: I'd use `<code>`.

Comment: You can try `<code>...</code>` - although I don't think there are standards for file paths.

Comment: a `<pre></pre>` tag would be most appropriate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Semantic HTML tag for displaying a path/directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868939/semantic-html-tag-for-displaying-a-path-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a semantic point of view, I'd go with an `ol` ordered list, since the path consists of a list of folders in which *order does matter*, optionally culminating in a filename.

Of course you'd have to adjust the standard CSS for `ol` so it looks like you want it to. Sample CSS that would also set the delimiters:

```css
.path {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.path li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
li[role=folder]::before,
li[role=file]::before {
  content: "/";
}
li[role=extension]::before {
  content: ".";  
}
```

```html
<div>Please find the configuration in
  <ol class="path" reversed="reversed">
    <li role="folder">etc</li>
    <li role="file">important</li>
    <li role="extension">conf</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

MDN elaborates on `<ol>` vs `<ul>` in a way that also reveals the semantics behind this approach:

> The `<ol>` and `<ul>` both represent a *list* of *items*. They differ in the way that, with the `<ol>` element, *the order is meaningful*. As a rule of thumb to determine which one to use, try changing the order of the list items; if the meaning is changed, the `<ol>` element should be used, else the `<ul>` is adequate.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol

Concerning the `reversed` attribute, I'd say it makes sense to assume the filename itself is always on `1.` regarding the order. That being said it would probably enhance semantics to not use two different `<li>` for file name and file extension, but rather split this into two `<span>` elements. On top of that, I want to point out that this approach allows for nice path "syntax" highlighting:

```css
.path {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.path li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
  font-weight: 600;
}
li[role=folder] {
  color: #00a;
}
li[role=file] {
  color: #a00;
}
li[role=folder]::before,
li[role=file]::before {
  content: "/";
  color: #888;
}
[role=file-extension] {
  color: #0a0;
  }
[role=file-extension]::before {
  content: ".";
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div>Please find the configuration in
  <ol class="path" reversed="reversed">
    <li role="folder">etc</li>
    <li role="folder">conf</li>
    <li role="file"><span role="file-name">important</span><span role="file-extension">cfg</span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

> The `reversed` attribute is a `boolean` attribute. If present, it indicates that the list is a descending list (..., 3, 2, 1). If the attribute is omitted, the list is an ascending list (1, 2, 3, ...).

[`<ol>` in the current HTML 5 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element)

Comment: Ingenious approach, I like this, although I'd like to comment that the file path exists in this case as a list. What if the user only has 1 folder that contains the files? Would the `<ol>` still be semantically correct if the list has 1 item?

Comment: Why would it not? Does a list necessarily have to consist of more than one item? I don't think so.

Comment: I see, merely thinking out loud here, semantics aren't subject to stone carved laws, so I'd question you why and how in this context. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 3):

For a single file path inside flowing text (as the OP is asking for), an option way better than `ol` and `mark` is [`code`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/textlevel-semantics.html#the-code-element):

> The code element represents a fragment of computer code. This could be
>   an XML element name, **a file name**, a computer program, or any other
>   string that a computer would recognize.

See also [Semantic HTML tag for displaying a path/directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868939/semantic-html-tag-for-displaying-a-path-directory/4869634#4869634) .

Answer (score 1):

#### HTML5 solution:

- In this case, I'd go for:

[The MARK tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark)

> The HTML Mark Element () represents highlighted text, i.e., a run of text marked for reference purpose, due to its relevance in a particular context. For example it can be used in a page showing search results to highlight every instance of the searched-for word.

With emphasis on the part where it says 'relevance in a particular context'.

> In the main text, the highlighted text typically marks text that may be of special relevance for the user's current activity, like search results.

This differs with `<strong>` or `<span>` because although the filepath requires special attention, it does not have more importance over the rest of your content, neither does it require syntax highlighting for which `<span>` should be used according to MDN.

#### And for non-HTML5 elements

If you cannot use HTML5 for some reason, [my best bet would be using](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) `<pre>`:

> The HTML  element (or HTML Preformatted Text) represents preformatted text. Text within this element is typically displayed in a non-proportional ("monospace") font exactly as it is laid out in the file. Whitespace inside this element is displayed as typed.

`<pre>` would display the filepath as a monotype font, giving not per se much semantic value, but more visual value to the string. The user would be informed of it's importance, but semantically, I wouldn't be going with this option if there was an alternative such as the `<mark>` tag. It also counts that you can choose to style the `<mark>` as a `<pre>`.

Then again you could also just use a `<span>`, `<kbd>` or even `<code>` for this section, or leave it out entirely. I'd just say that `<mark>` is the most semantically correct solution.

I would brag I knew this, but I had to [look up my sources](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp) for this as well.

Comment: That's alot of suggestions. I miss your explanation of why the suggested approaches do well semantic-wise?

Comment: @connexo That's entirely correct. I've missed the point I was trying to make by stating all options here. I've elaborated each option, and stated my own opinion what *I* would use in this case.

Comment: I'd assume the `bdi` tag is meant to be used for example to mark up a bit of `rtl` text inside otherwise `ltr` text (e.g. Arabic in English). A file path is not a bit of such text that requires changing direction or has unknown direction. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction

Comment: Using  `bdi` would even force you to make it *obsolete* by applying `direction: ltr;` explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I did indeed mess up on the Bi Directional path. I've removed the snippet from the answer, since it would definitely *not* be semantically correct. I'm still reading up on this though, seems like there are some more uses for it.

Comment: `mark` also does not seem a valid approach here. The specs explain what this element is meant to convey: *When used in the main prose of a document, it indicates a part of the document that has been* ***highlighted due to its likely relevance to the user's current activity.*** I don't see how a file path fits in that. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-mark-element

Comment: Regarding relevance and importance, `mark` isn't reserved for the example you're describing.  *The following example shows the difference between denoting the importance of a span of text (strong) as opposed to denoting the relevance of a span of text (mark). It is an extract from a textbook, where the extract has had the parts relevant to the exam highlighted.* In addition, the actual w3 description states *The mark element represents a run of text in one document marked or highlighted for reference purposes, due to its relevance in another context.* which does seem to fit it's purpose.